# (REACT) Is there a way to append the value of a variable without triggering not defined

Tags: reactjs, loops, variables, react-native

So I'm trying to append the value of a variable like so:

```
state = { value: "" };

componentWillMount() {
  _this.setState({
    value: value + newValue
   })
}
```

However the error I keep getting is that it thinks the value is not defined.
I tried using a conditional for only appending when not undefined but that didn't seem to work either. I might be missing something trivial, any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

`value` is not defined inside your `componentWillMount`. You have to access the `value` from the state by writing `this.state.value`.

However, if you are deriving a state update from what is currently in state, you should give a function to `setState` and return the update instead.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    return { value: previousState.value + newValue };
  })
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate why you should use the previousState callback like that? I've never come across that before.

Comment: @MikeBell I think the [documentation of `setState` is a great read on the subject](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). "If the next state depends on the previous state, we recommend using the updater function form, instead"

Comment: Thanks. I also found this to be a good read after some googling. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Answer (score 2):

Your code, as posted, doesn't work for a lot of reasons, but I think what you're looking for is to reference `this.state.value` rather than `value`.

i.e.

```
componentWillMount() {
   _this.setState({
      value: _this.state.value + newValue
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you are referencing in your set state call is not defined as it is the object property you are assigning to. You will need to use this.state.value to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the componentWillMount `value` is not defined. To acess the actual state you must use `this.state.value`. And you might wanna use the `funtional setState` as `general setState` may not provide the most recently updated state due to the fact that setState is itself  `asynchronous` due to `Object Composition` in React.